Как получить значение из chekbox php?
Пытаюсь получить значение из нажатого пользователем chekbox, и в зависимости от того какое это значение запустить соответствующую сортировку, однако не выходит. Просто не получается получить значение после нажатия. Не знаете в чем может быть причина проблемы и как ее исправить?
            <form methog="POST">
                <li><p><input type="checkbox" name="sort[]" value="new"/>Новые</p></li>
                <li><p><input type="checkbox" name="sort[]" value="popular"/>Популярные</p></li>
            </form>

        function sortTo(&$wallpapers, $sort) {
            usort($wallpapers, function ($a, $b) use ($sort) {
                return $a[$sort] <=> $b[$sort];
            });
            return $wallpapers;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['sort'])) {
            $sort = $_POST['sort'];
            if ($sort == 'new') {
                $sort = 'uploadDate';
                $wallpapers = sortTo($wallpapers, $sort);
                echo "<h1>$sort</h1>"; // Проверка на получение результата
            } else if ($sort == 'popular') {
                $sort = 'numDown';
                $wallpapers = sortTo($wallpapers, $sort);
                echo "<h1>$sort</h1>";
            }
        }


Во-первых, непонятно, почему здесь чекбокс, а не радио. А во-вторых, с чего вы решили, что нажатие на чекбокс отправляет форму на сервер? Наверное, форму отправляет какой-то другой элемент?
